# c# - Dynamically created table and adjusting TextBox length

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the code below (which is in loop - not shown!), the length of the string contained in TextBox is too long. How can I fix this? Also, is it possible to use a TextView instead of a TextBox?

```
TableCell tc = new TableCell();
TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
txtBox.Text = reader.GetString(col);
// Add the control to the TableCell
tc.Controls.Add(txtBox);
// Add the TableCell to the TableRow
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
col++;
```

Comment: Also i want the first column in the table to be a hyperlink with the data in the first column cell a post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would rather have a text, use a `Label` instead of `TextBox`. Like that:

```
TableCell tc = new TableCell();
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = reader.GetString(col);
// Add the control to the TableCell
tc.Controls.Add(label);
// Add the TableCell to the TableRow
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
col++;
```

Now, if you want to have control over the TextBox width, you can just set it:

```
txtBox.Width = 40; //or whatever value suits your needs
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea how the first column data can be hyperlinked for the user?

Comment: @Downvoter, please have the decency of commenting why the downvote

Comment: @Beginner Yes, you can use a `HyperLink` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you question, could you rephrase? Or maybe post a new question if that applies?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the label control instead of the textbox, if you just want to display to the user the text and don't want them to edit it.